# Sitecore ECM Slow to Process/Dispatch

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-ecm

I have a client who is using the ECM and just dispatched an email blast to approximately 18,000 users. The dispatch is taking quite a while (about 2 hours to process not even half of the users).

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Can the ECM not handle such large lists?

Comment: I know of customers using ECM that blasts millions of emails using ECM and this is done in under one hour.

Comment: I would start by checking the logs and analyze the traffic between the Sitecore instance and the MTA. Further on there is a lot of configuration settings for optizing the performance of ECM.

Comment: Are you doing a lot of personalization? For customers with large analytics DBs and little server power this can cause ECM to be very slow.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned elsewhere, ECM can handle that load just fine. In general, throughput on ECM is limited by:

- Fragmented indices on the "analytics" database (or just limited capacity on same)
- Bandwidth limitations. If each mail is 500KB (lots of images), sending 10 mails per second requires 5Mbit bandwidth
- CPU on the server in question

From what you've shared so far, I cannot guess as to which of the above is limiting the throughput on your installation. My personal guess would be capacity and speed of the database.

More information here: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/ecm/200/ecm_tuning_guide_20-a4.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with a client where it was taking hours to send emails.  Check the `NumberThreads` setting in the `Sitecore.EmailCampaign.config` file.  The default is quite low at "1" and most servers should be able to handle more threads.

Definitely follow the tuning guide that Mark posted.  The `Performance Measurement Tool` can help you get the ideal number of sending threads so that you're not over or under utilizing your server.